# Get current playback type of HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Is there a way to find out wether the applied SRC to the video element contains audio, video or both? I am using this for a media player, but want to determine when the video element should be visible, or when the audio spectrum shall be displayed.
(Btw I want to achieve this in javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the video element's `videoWidth` / `videoHeight` property after the `onloadedmetadata` event fires. If it is equal to `0`, it does not have a video track.

Webkit also supports the `webkitVideoDecodedByteCount` and `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` attributes, but that won't help you on other browsers.

And of course you always query the file type by checking the src's extension:

- if (mp3 | oga | etc) -> assume audio only
- if (mp4 | ogv | webm | etc) -> assume video

Answer (score 1):

As TimHayes says, you can check the file extension, but that doesn't always help you. You could have .ogg, which is ambiguous, or the URL might point to some server-side script that doesn't expose the file extension.

When in doubt, the `<video>` element will play either one, so you can just use that. Then check `videoWidth` after `loadedmetadata` fires (or if `.readyState > 0`, in case the metadata loads before you attach the event listener).

If you find there's no video track, you'll want to hide or at least shrink the video element. It's probably best if you write your own controls so they don't look weird.

Comment: That about the extensions was how I first did it, but that doesn't work for such files. I already have the controls and are just hiding everything